# Shared Folders Space Usage

Tags: ubuntu-one, shared-folders, quota

I am a new user moving from Dropbox. The gripe I have with Dropbox is that it takes the shared folders size into account for your disk quota. Is it the same with Ubuntu One?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

No, shared folders from other users do not affect your own usage quota. However, if you give someone else write access to a share you offer to them, they can put files in it, which will affect your quota (as you own the share).